# Angular 2 easier way to use route navigate query parameters

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a string of query parameter values ie:

```
var querys = "agentId=5&page=2&name=andrew"
```

Is there an easier way to use this exact string to get to that page using `this.router.navigate` otherwise I'll have to manually list it all out like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/admin/list'], { queryParams: { agentId: 5, page: 2, name: andrew } });
```

And of course that gets messy if I don't always know what the query param keys names are going to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use below code

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(`/admin/list?${querys}`);
```

Comment: I never knew this existed. Thanks so much that worked great :)

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward any time. If it solves your issue please mark it as answer, so other devs having same issue easily can find the answer then